# How do I use a local annoationProcessor

Tags: java, gradle, annotations

Trying my hand at annotationProcessors of my own. I have a subproject located within my main project which has one.

Every example I see, the annotationProcessor goes down to the class level, I'm trying to figure out how to do that with the local 'ToolsProject' as well, was hoping I could chase the package through.

Any advice? I've been struggling with this for a while now

```
implementation project(':ToolsProject')

annotationProcessor project(':ToolsProject.AutoLog:AutoLogProcessor')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you declare there is a dependency, you cannot depend on a class, so it would just be `annotationProcessor project(':ToolsProject')`.

By default all annotation processors on the path are invoked I think and if you would want to restrict that, you do it with `jvmArg` on the respective `JavaCompile` task, using the parameter `-processor` with the classes you want to run as comma-separated list if you are not happy with the default discovery result.